# Обработка большого xml файла на PHP

Tags: xml, php

Здравствуйте
Нужно обработать большой XML файл (40 МБ)

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents('2013-03-14-09-43.tov'));  
foreach ($xml->unit as $value) { /*Обработка*/ }
```

Структура файла такая:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <product list="Номенклатура">
        <unit articul="Б-0194247" articul_cat="Б-0220009" double_articul_cat="" name="Батарейка Axent 5556 R06"/>
        <unit articul="Б-0194247" articul_cat="Б-0220009" double_articul_cat="" name="Батарейка Axent 5556 R06"/>
    </product>
```

Но из-за большого размера файла, к обработки дело не доходит. 
Маленькие файлы(до 5 МБ) обрабатываются нормально.
Как мне быть?

Спасибо!

Comment: Вот ещё вариант велосипеда: Конечный автомат.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Три варианта

- улучшить комп, добавить памяти, подкрутить php.ini
- перейти на sax парсер.
- писать свой парсер.

я за второй вариант. третий для любителей.

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно потоковое чтение xml. [ссылка](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.xmlreader.php)

Answer (score 0):

Может стоит разделить файл? А после обработки уже собрать обработанные. 40 метров текста это довольно много, не каждый сервант с таким сладит, чего говорить об обычном компе?